# Jqplot sometimes showing wrong values in highlighter if the line is curly

Tags: jqplot

My jqplot graph's highlighter is showing a wrong value if the line is curly.
Here on the image attached you can see that it's showing value 49% above number 50 that is shown on the y-axes, and it should be below.

I don't know why is that happening and how can I fix it. Any suggestions?

[Wrong value shown in highlighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2xcO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some source code?

Anyway, in jqplot there is a way to customize the labels tick.
For example you can add a 'formatter' function, to manipulate the tick data and format. Like:

```
...
    options.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatter = function(format,value) {
                return xAxiformatter(value).toFixed(2);
            }
...
    function xAxiformatter(value) {
                return -4.57 + xSlope * (value - modMinX);
            }
...
```

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasAxisTickRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer.formatter

You can use this formatter function also to make a "workaround" solution for the problem.